# Post FB comment as page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have administrator account of a Facebook page, i would like to know whether it is possible to post a comment as page (the one i manage) using graph api and how to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: RTFM: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/comments#publish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this link will be of help to you
It does cover most of the information

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing